# Dask parallelization with df.iterrows()

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, multiprocess, dask-dataframe

I want to parallel iterate over dask dataframe these code:

```
    from dask import dataframe
    dataset_df = dataframe.read_csv('input.csv')

    for x, row in dataset_df.iterrows():
       similarity = []
       for y, item in dataset_df.iterrows():
          similarity.append(similarity_text(row['text'], item['text']))
       result['similarity'] = similarity
```

Many thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a GPU you can try cudf: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/pandas-dataframe-tutorial-beginners-guide-to-gpu-accelerated-dataframes-in-python/.

If not, you're going to run into trouble due to global interpreter lock. You could always use numpy and take advantage of its vectorised operations.

Comment: I'm not using GPU